# Conditional Moose::Role consumption

Tags: perl, moose

I have a `Moose` class, that is consuming a Role like ...

```
package MyPackage;
use Moose;

with 'MyRole';

# ...

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

My goal is, to only use a role, when another module is installed on the running system without creating a new dependency in my modules. When the module is not available the normal package functionality should be used, without the role and without crashing.

I already found `ensure_all_roles` and `apply_all_roles` in [Moose::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose%3a%3aUtil). I tried to write a method, that calls them when my conditions are fulfilled. But since I want my class to be immutable, the application crashes...

```
The 'add_package_symbol' method cannot be called on an immutable instance
```

That makes sense to me.

My question is: How to apply a role under a given condition for a class, that is marked as immutable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following

```
with 'MyRole' if $condition;
```

It works without errors for both truth values of $condition.